Laravel not recognize my created custom class
I created a custom file named ZibalRequest.php in laravel Controllers directory and here is my file :
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

class ZibalRequest
{


public function sendSmsOtp($amount , $invoice_name , $user_mobile)
{

    return 'boo';
    
}


}

and called it in my controller this way :
        $ee = new ZibalRequest();
    $ee->sendSmsOtp(    $amount,
        $invoice_name,
        $user_mobile
    );

I think I named files and namespaces correctly but I'm getting this error :
Class "App\Http\Controllers\ZibalRequest" not found

What's wrong with laravel?

Try composer dumpautoload on the command line.

@aynber I tried it before, but not resolves the problem

I tried the same code and tested it, and it's working fine on my side.
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

class ZibalRequest
{
    public static function sendSmsOtp($amount, $invoice_name, $user_mobile)
    {
        return 'boo';
    }
}

Other Controller where you call the class.
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

class OtherController extends Controller
{
  public function index()
    {
        $amount = 10;
        $invoice_name = 'ddd';
        $user_mobile = 1111111;
    
        $ee = new ZibalRequest();
        return  $ee->sendSmsOtp($amount, $invoice_name, $user_mobile);

    }
    }

It returns 'boo' when I hit the index() method from the router.
Please share more code.

Extend controller class in defined controller, Like below
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

class ZibalRequest extends Controller
{


   public function sendSmsOtp($amount , $invoice_name , $user_mobile)
   {

    return 'boo';
    
   }


}


I extended it as controller but not works

Try to clear cache

I cleared cache but not works ...

You may have not imported the right namespace, try to share the full screen shot of the controller class you have implemented the ZibalRequest class
